# Seq.take won't return elements

Tags: visual-studio, f#

When I run the following code:

```
getTheData() |> Seq.take 3
```

it does not return the elements, instead it outputs this:

```
val it : seq<Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<ID,Data>>
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and F# Interactive
What is wrong, should it not output the first 3 items?

getTheData function =

```
let getTheData() =
    (@"C:\Users\data.xlsx")
    |> (ParseExcel >> datap)
    |> Seq.distinct
    |> Seq.map(fun b -> b.ID, b)
    |> Map.ofSeq
```

Comment: Try adding `|> Seq.toList`. Sequences are lazy and FSI doesn't always evaluate their elements.

Answer (score 2):

`Seq.take` is not considered a terminal operation on a sequence in F#.  As mentioned in the comments, sequences are lazily evaluated, and only operations that are considered "terminal" will cause a sequence to be iterated.  Terminal operations include `Seq.iter` (if you want to perform an action on each element) and `Seq.toList` (if you want a materialized list of each element), as well as others like `Seq.exactlyOne`.

In F# interactive, you can probably just evaluate `it` to see the first few values.  In the following example mirroring yours, evaluating `it` at the end will display the 3 values taken:

```
open System

let getTheData() =
    seq {
        for n in {0..1000} -> Guid.NewGuid(), n
    } |> Map.ofSeq

getTheData()
|> Seq.take 3;;

it;;
val it : seq<Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<Guid,int>> =
  seq
    [[001830fe-9ce3-4649-8609-571e4aedb4c7, 791]
       {Key = 001830fe-9ce3-4649-8609-571e4aedb4c7;
        Value = 791;};
     [001bf0a9-5981-4bc0-bcaf-046af7f4866a, 383]
       {Key = 001bf0a9-5981-4bc0-bcaf-046af7f4866a;
        Value = 383;};
     [004b44a7-85d2-4ce5-91bf-49bcc44f03ba, 91]
       {Key = 004b44a7-85d2-4ce5-91bf-49bcc44f03ba;
        Value = 91;}]
```